# Can I bring portable closet from India to USA?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airlines, regulations

I have portable closet which I want to take with me from India to the USA. The parts consists of 20 steel tubes which fit inside a suitcase. Can I carry those in my checked baggage?

Answer (score 17):

Nothing to stop you taking your closet as long as it fits in a suitcase or box which fits within the size and weight limits of the airline.

But unless it is a special design or a piece of furniture that has a high personal value, I would not bother. Better take those things you can not buy where you go and do not pay for extra luggage, (but that is my view rather than fact.)
Buying a new closet or having your current one send to you will likely be cheaper for a long stay, and for a short stay you can likely do without the closet or buy a cheap alternative (maybe second hand.)

Based on the comments a warning:
Having that many steel tubes in your luggage may mean that it will be checked extra. Often that is by opening the case and having a look, likely with a dog trained to smell explosives near. It can also 'just' be a different scanner and an electronic device to check for explosives.

Comment: Yes and as someone who has moved countries with a lot of my stuff in extra baggage let me add this piece of advice: also include in your cost analysis physically lugging that stuff both from and to the airports :-)

Comment: Many people living elsewhere do visit their home country occasionally. Whenever I do, I also bring as much stuff back to my new home with me as I can. The space is otherwise wasted. I think the answer and comments should just stick to the facts.

Comment: It would be considered weird merely because who ships furniture halfway around the world unless it's an antique?  USA is a perfectly sophisticated and modern country, and it does in fact have furniture. Some of it is very reasonably priced, hit up http://www.ikea.com/ and see for yourself.

Comment: @WoJ If you are just wanting to move a relatively small amount of stuff (i.e. will fit into a couple of suitcases) taking it as checked luggage is often the cheapest (and most straightforward) way to move it. Extra checked bags typically cost in the region of $50 -$100. In many countries customs agents' fees for shipped items alone can be significantly more than that.

Comment: There's a chance of a funny terminology issue -- I'm not sure how "closest" is used in Indian English.  An exhibition booth, for example, could also be described as portable and consist of a load of steel tubes (with panels or flexible sheeting between them)

Comment: @ChrisH true - I had a "water closet" on my mind initially.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I couldn't make that work in my head, so initally assumed a [collapsible wardrobe](https://www.argos.co.uk/product/4609830) before thinking again

Comment: @ChrisH portable toilets exist https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ATMqnZWjL._SL1000_.jpg but the idea of packing one of them into a checked baggage in order to take it to another continent seems quite funny.